# Project folder is not showing on localhost project list

Tags: .htaccess

here i am going to maintain the website .. where i transfer the whole file of site from server to localhost.. but website is not showing in the list of localhost...
What can be the issue?? Is this issue of .htaccess??? my .htaccess has ..

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 300 days"
</FilesMatch>

#Enable Compression
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In your Apache's httpd.conf uncomment below lines and then restart Apache.

```
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

Alternatively you can update your .htaccess compression section as displayed below:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    and so on...
</IfModule>
```